# How to define ActiveXObject in selenium.geEval method?

Tags: javascript, selenium-rc

i'm using selenium rc for automation i used selenium.GetEval(" var fso = new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject')"); but it shows activex not defined error during run time..

Comment: selenium.GetEval(" var fso = new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject')");
it will work only IE not in FireFox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

selenium.GetEval(" var fso = new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject')"); it will work only IE not in FireFox.